# regex catastrophic backtrack issue

Tags: regex, backtracking

I am trying to scan the following type of files. Files exists of specific blocks that alternate serially, for example:

```
**Block A starts**
-some data- **Block B starts**
-some data- ***END***---- **Block A starts**
-some data- **Block B starts**
-some data- ***END***---- etc etc.
```

This file can be very large (for example 500gb).
I am trying to scan the file using a regex to get the data of each block, for example:

> [[block A data, block B data], [block A data, block B data]]

The way i was trying to do it at start was with this regex:

```
"Block A starts(.+?)Block B starts(.+?)END"
```

if the file was in this format, everything was ok, but this regex had issues if for example Block B did not appear in the log file. I think i had the backtracking issue. I read that you had to use atomic groups to remove backtracking, so i wrote this regex:

```
"(?=(?P<group1>.+?Block B starts))(?P=group1)(?=(?P<group2>.+?END))(?P=group2)"
```

but still had the same issue. I also tried this regex in order to make it stop if it reaches the end of file, but still ahd no success.

```
"(?=(?P<group1>.+?(?:Block B starts|\Z)))(?P=group1)(?=(?P<group2>.+?(?:END|\Z)))(?P=group2)"
```

If the regex is not matching the file correctly, it takes forever to complete with large files.

Anyone has any idea how i can fix the regex in order both to match correctly the file but also make it fail quickly if any of those blocks does not exist.

(I am using python with the default re module)

Comment: It is a lot easier to help you if you provide data of all blocks and if you specify which programming language you are using.

Comment: This sounds like you are reading the entire file into memory so you can apply a regex to it. That's converniet if you have the memory, but won't scale to really big files, and frequently causes monumental disasters when the regex wants to attempt to match the entire file over and over. Reading a line at a time and deciding what to do with it based on a simple state machine might be a better approach. Sounds like about three lines of Awk, or maybe thirty in Python.

Comment: It isn't a backtracking issue since you use non-greedy quantifiers (the backtracking mechanism occurs only with greedy quantifiers). The problem is that your file is too large, whatever the "optimized pattern" you project to use, if one of the literal substrings in your pattern isn't found in your string, the regex engine has to search until the end. tripleee suggestion is the good one: read your file line by line.

Comment: i am using mmap to load the file. As far as i know it doesn't load the file in memory, instead it reads it from disk. Although i am not sure, because i do see increase in memory of the process. I choose not to read the file line by lien because data of each block might span multiple lines. I am not really sure how i can do this using state machine and/or awk. What i dont understand is that when the file is in the correct format, the the regex DOES read the whole file to scan every block, yet it finishes in 20 sec. But when the file is not in the correct format, then it takes ages.